# Why do the levels of indirection not match the number of memory accesses in C?

Tags: c

I've been thinking about this for about a month now and have no resolution.

```
int* (*arr)[5];

int n[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int* arr_l2[5] = {&n[0], &n[1], &n[2], &n[3]};

arr = &arr_l2;

printf("%d \n", *((*arr)[2]));  // outputs 2, accessed using n[2]
printf("%p \n", *((*arr)+2));   // outputs address 0x7ffd793894e8, stack address holding value 2
```

Consider this code. Why would the second printf() not output 2 with the dereferencing schemes used? To me, it seems to make intuitive sense that it would because using pointer arithmetic:

*(arr + 2) is the equivalent of arr[2]

Additionally, what exactly is a & reference? I only realized today that reference parameters may be used as the variable itself, and are not like pointers, which must be dereferenced. A former professor of mine had said that pointers and references are the same, but this is obviously not true.

Could I please get a simple but thorough explanation on the number of dereferences, the reference operator, and this subtle mismatch?

Comment: "I only realized today that reference parameters may be used as the variable itself, and are not like pointers, which must be dereferenced." You're mixing up C++ with C. The use of `&` here has *nothing* to do with C++ references, it's creating a C pointer. There are *no* special reference types here (or anywhere in C) that directly refer to the variable and don't require dereferencing.

Comment: _"Why would the second not output 2?"_ The second uses the format specifier `%p` which outputs a pointer value.

Comment: Your compiler is likely smart enough to nuke some levels of indirection in your code. It knows that `arr` points to `arr_l2` and so `*arr` is really `arr_l2`.  Further it knows that `arr_l2[2]` is really `&n[2]` and so when that is dereferenced it is really `n[2]`. And `n[]` is not assigned anywhere so it knows that `n[2]` is 2.  Basically the entire expression ` *((*arr)[2])` can be reduced to `2` at compile time, so there is no indirection.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right that I am. In C++, what exactly is a reference parameter? It seems to function like a pointer, but without the need of dereferencing, and I read on another thread that it occupies stack space, though I haven't verified this myself.

Comment: @paddy I used "%p" because it was outputting an incoherent number when it was "%d", and I wanted to use "%p" to see if it aligned with the stack address.

Comment: @Kaz My question is why the second would not also be "2" at compile-time. I'll edit the question for clarity.

Comment: @cspurposesonly: That is a *wholly* separate question, but conveniently, it's already answered [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/364696). In the future, don't ask multiple, largely unrelated questions together.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing syntax, `a[i]` is *exactly* equivalent to `*(a + i)` (it's so equivalent that `somearray[5]` can legally be written as `5[somearray]`, since addition is commutative, so `*(somearray + 5)` and `*(5 + somearray)` do the same thing). So

```
printf("%d \n", *((*arr)[2]));
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d \n", *(*((*arr) + 2)));
```

Note the three dereferencing `*`s. Your other statement only has two (and no implicit dereferencing via `[i]`), so it's only dereferencing two out of three layers of pointers, and does not reach the same value.

On "what exactly is a & reference? I only realized today that reference parameters may be used as the variable itself, and are not like pointers, which must be dereferenced." you're likely reading up on C++ references (which have the "no explicit dereference required" behavior). They don't exist in C. `arr = &arr_l2;` just says "Take the address of `arr_12` and put it in `arr`", but it's still explicitly taking the address, and therefore reaching the underlying value will require one level of dereferencing (via `*`, `->` or indexing syntax).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No professor ever has given me that first explanation. That's exactly what I was looking for. For the second, you're right. I was asking about C++ and not C; I should've been more clear. I still would like an answer on it though.

Comment: @cspurposesonly: C++ references [are a well-covered topic already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/364696).

Comment: @cspurposesonly You tagged your question as C language question. C++ is a very different language. If you want to ask about C++ you would need to use C++ language tag instead of C tag.